# How to get a shipping method names in admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get a shipping method names in admin grid in Magento 2.

[image]

I tried like  the below way..

xml file

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="methods">
  <arguments>
     <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" 
      translate="true">Method</argument>
    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">methods</argument>
    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">150px</argument>
    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
    <argument name="renderer" 
 xsi:type="string">Bg\ShippingRestriction\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier\ShippingMethod </argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
```

> Bg\ShippingRestriction\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier\ShippingMethod.php

```
<?php 
namespace Bg\ShippingRestriction\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier; 
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods;
class ShippingMethod extends AbstractRenderer
{
      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scope,
        Allmethods $allmethods,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Config $shippingConfig,
        array $data = array()
    )
    {
        $this->scope = $scope;
        $this->allmethods = $allmethods;
        $this->_shippingConfig = $shippingConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $shippingMethods = explode(',', $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
        $methodList     = $this->allmethods->toOptionArray();

        $result = '';
        foreach ($shippingMethods as $method) {
            $result .= $methodList[$method]['label'].',';
        }


        return rtrim($result, ',');
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the data you saved in  database related to shipping method?

Comment: here is the database data https://prnt.sc/q5hh14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method

Note: Not tested

```
protected $shippingmodelconfig;

public function __construct(
  ........
  \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
){
    ........
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $shippingMethods = explode(',', $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
    $result = '';
    foreach ($shippingMethods as $method) {
      $carrierCode = explode("_", $method);
      $carrierTitle = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/'. $carrierCode[0].'/title');          
      $result .= $carrierTitle.',';
    }
    return rtrim($result, ',');
}
```

Comment: i tried the above one, its reflects blank again  https://prnt.sc/q5hucd

Comment: Ok let me check in my env.

Comment: @divyasekar I have updated. Please check now

Comment: Above code works well